# browserify standalone bundle not found when building create-react-app for deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm coding a react application and I need some packages that are only available on node. I decided to go with browserify and make a standalone bundle. this works correctly locally and am able to use the bundled packages, but when I npm run build it says that my imports are not found.